# javascript window.event coming up null?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I am using a CustomValidator in ASP.NET as follows:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvComment" ControlToValidate="txtComment" Display="None"
        EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="validateComment"
    runat="server" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And this is the function that gets called:

```
function validateComment(source, args) {
            var reComment = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9',!;?@#%*.\s]{1,1000}$");
            var validComment = reComment.test(window.event.srcElement.value);
            if (!validComment)
                alert("The comment has illegal characters");
            args.IsValid = validComment;
        }
```

Upon clicking the button that triggers the validator, the application breaks and I can see that the `window.event` property is null, so obviously there's a null reference trying to match the regEx. My question is why could the window.event be showing up as null? I could've sworn this was working before.

EDIT:

I have modified the function as such:

```
   var check = document.getElementById(source.id);
   var checky = check.attributes["controltovalidate"].value;
   var checkyo = document.getElementById(checky);
   var validHour = reOutHour.test(checkyo.value);
   if (!validHour)
        alert("The time is incorrectly formatted");
   args.IsValid = validHour;
```

Now this is working on Internet Explorer, but not on Firefox...

Comment: Which browser are you testing? `window.event` is IE proprietary stuff.  In other browsers, the event object is passed as the first argument of the handling function.

Comment: How would I modify that to support both browsers?

Comment: "source" (first argument) is the DOM element to test, use it to be compatible with any browser.

Comment: What are those two arguments to "validateComment()"?  Can you find in the ASP-generated mess where the actual call to that function is?

Comment: First argument (source) is the tested dom element, second argument (args) contains a property isValid that you set to true or false depending on whether validation succeeded or failed.

Comment: How can I find the control that I need to validate using 'source'? There's too many properties in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve my problem:

```
var check = document.getElementById(source.id);
   var checky = check.controltovalidate;
   var checkyo = document.getElementById(checky);
   var validHour = reOutHour.test(checkyo.value);
   if (!validHour)
        alert("The time is incorrectly formatted");
   args.IsValid = validHour;
```